# How can I incorporate sequel types into my project typings file?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, typescript-typings

I want to incorporate into my root typings (`/index.d.ts`) some types belonging to `sequel` that are defined in `@types/sequel/index.d.ts`.

I know that I cannot import it because a typings file is not a module. And I know that I can use references.

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/sequelize/index.d.ts" />
```

However, I cannot put any types into one of my types as such:

```
type ConnectionOptions = {
    databaseName: string,
    user: string,
    password: string,
    connectionUrl: string,
    options: sequelize.Options
};
```

It errors out saying

> [ts] Cannot find namespace 'sequelize'.

Am I missing something in my tsconfig.json?

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build",
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": false,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "ES5",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "lib": ["es2015"],
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }
}
```

I must be understanding quite badly the typings mechanism behind typescript (eg: namespacing).

Comment: `import` them from the appropriate file/module

Comment: Did you try to import the sequelize module?

Comment: The rest of my project goes haywire if I import anything into my `index.d.ts` file. It's as though my d.ts file stopped being recognized as such and its types are no longer resolvable from my other ts files